# How to change Greek letter lambda into italic in LaTeX

Tags: math, latex

I'd like to change "lambda" into italic style in LaTeX,I succeed in "\Sigma" by changing it into "\varSigma",but failed to do it when it comes to "lambda". Is this "\lambda" I get is already italic?Or is there a way to change it?I'm looking forward to your reply.

```
\Sigma \to \varSigma
\lambda \\
```

Comment: A lowercase `\lambda` is already italic. It's easier to see for the other lowercase Greek letters; see page 2 of the [LaTeX Symbol List](https://www3.nd.edu/~nmark/UsefulFacts/LaTeX_symbols.pdf). There's the [upgreek](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/was/upgreek.pdf) package for those who want an upright version.

Comment: FYI - there's a [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange community you might consider joining if you venture further into LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

This "\lambda" is already italic
Thank Thomas,your comment have solved my question!Thank you!